# FAQ additions for answers/comments

Tags: discussion

The mods have noticed several repeated problems that perhaps some verbiage in our FAQ could help.  Our proposed amendments:

- Not everything here has an objectively correct answer, but subjective
  answers should be backed up with real play experience. See [Good
  Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for how to answer subjective questions on Stack Exchange.
- There are many different tastes in games and different kinds of
  playstyle. All styles are welcome here, but attacking others' styles
  as wrong is not. As a rule, answer questions in the style they were
  asked - telling someone "they are playing wrong" is usually unwelcome and not constructive.
- Comments are for asking for clarification or providing constructive
  feedback on answers and should not be long discussion threads;
  comments are considered temporary and will be cleaned up by mods. If
  you have a major point to make, write your own answer and let people vote on it.  Comment warring will not be tolerated.

Feedback?

Comment: Changes applied to the FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with this, especially point 3. Comments are temporary. If you've got a point to make that *fits* with the question, make it in your own answer. If you have a side point to make as a function of the other person's answer, make a new question that directly addresses the problem (so long as you have standing -- specifically that it's a question that has come up in your role-playing experience.)

Comment: +1 Agree. As a new user, I still find commenting a little confusing. Before 50 rep, I was often tempted to comment and add a check-this-link-too comment. It takes some time to realize that is not the intended SE Q&A format.

Comment: +1 comments being temporary helps keep the format clean. Voting, since it never "closes" even after an answer is accepted, ought to take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Seconded. In addition to what Brian Ballsun-Stanton mentions, I agree with point three because I myself have misused the comment thread before learning the *de facto* of it's use. The first point is a good segway to the second, and I've seen a lot of the second so clarification is unfortunately necessary.